# How to use the FASM Console for Compiling

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, console, fasm

I am trying to make an assembly IDE that lets the user enter code and compile it with NASM, FASM, YASM, etc. However, since FASM comes with an IDE, I can't find any information on compiling with the console. For example, if I had a program test.asm, would I compile like this:

```
fasm test.asm
```

If I did, fasm.exe would have to be in the same directory as command prompt was operating I assume. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your building an IDE for use with multiple Assemblers?  Create a settings file (maybe a project file) and let the user enter the path for the their Assemblers.  You then pass this info onto, in your case FASM.  You could look at RadASM and WinASM, both are awesome Assembly IDEs with source.

Something similar to this:
[image: RadASM Paths]

And this:
[image: Project Settings]

All this gets saved to a project file
When the project is opened, load the paths and pass on to the assembler/linker/res compilers command line.

Answer (score 0):

Set `PATH` to wherever fasm.exe is, and set `INCLUDE` to wherever the fasm includes are, and everything should work as you expect.

Comment: You mean in the code? So I should run the console command like in the question after setting PATH and INCLUDE?

Comment: Yes, as you have several assemblers to choose from, each which could use its own `INCLUDE`, you should set it before assembling. `SetEnvironmentVariable` might be what you would want to use. If you use the full path to `fasm.exe`, you wouldn´t need to set `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide the output file name and path directly in the command line:

```
fasm source/path/source.asm destination/path/output.exe
```

When you omit the last argument, fasm will try to guess the extension based on the format directive inside the source.